# Selenium: Scraping text from a website is outputting the wrong thing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've currently written some basic Selenium code which opens a web-browser, goes to Google Shopping, searches a product via it's EAN, goes to the compare section and then takes a screenshot of the page and saves it. I've been trying to change this to scrape the Google Shopping price comparison page but when I try this:

```py
    print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tiOgyd'))
```

it outputs

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b4b504606e9da50eb8127876c6da4d33", element="0.10149917790191187-1")>
```

which means absolutely nothing to me.

'tiOgyd' is the price section of the table in Google Shopping, shown in the image below

[[image: Google Shopping tiOgyd[1]]

The end goal is to be able to organise and save the sellers and buyers into a file eventually for price comparison.

I was hoping someone here could explain why it's not outputting what I expected and help me fix it. Thank you.

Comment: what are you expecting it to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tiOgyd')` is an object

try

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tiOgyd')[0].get_attribute('outerHTML')  
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tiOgyd')[0].get_attribute('innerHTML') 
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tiOgyd')[0].text
```

you can use `driver.find_element_by_class_name` if you expect only one class to have this name